# How many times does the sign change in my vector?

Tags: r, vector

I would like you to help me to create a function that helps me to identify how many times does the sign of the numbers in a vector change, for example:
1,2,-5,-6,-7,5,1,-8
How could my function identify that there are 3 sign changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code below

```
> sum(diff(sign(v))!=0)
[1] 3
```

or

```
> sum(rowSums(embed(sign(v), 2)) == 0)
[1] 3
```

**Data**

```
v <- c(1, 2, -5, -6, -7, 5, 1, -8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rle` :

```
x <- c(1, 2, -5, -6, -7, 5, 1, -8)

length(rle(sign(x))$lengths) - 1
#[1] 3
```